How does the state function affect my counter variable?
I am currently working on React.js. I'm encountering some issues while working with React state hooks.
here is my code,
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default function Todo() {
  var [Todo, Settodo] = useState()

  var counter = 0

  var Addtodo = () => {
    var input = document.getElementById('input')
    var list = document.createElement('li')
    var inputval= input.value
    console.log(counter)
    Settodo(Todo = inputval)
    list.textContent = Todo 
    list.setAttribute("id",`lsit-val-${counter}`)
    document.getElementById("Todo-list").appendChild(list)
    counter++
  }

  return (
    <>
      <center>
        <h1>Todo</h1>
        <input id="input" type="text" />
        <button onClick={Addtodo}>ADD</button>
        <div id="Todo-list"></div>
      </center>
    </>
  )
}

Here at my Addtodo function I tried to increment my counter variable value but it doesn't produce the expected output. Instead it returns '0' for twice for fist two clicking event amd I don't know why this is happening. If I tried the same thing without using Settodo() it works just fine. Can someone explain me what is exactly happening here?
here is my output 
I searched through various articles and websites but I cant find any reasonable solutions.

counter should be a state value.  It's being re-declared to 0 on every render.  (Though there are other problems here as well...)

You generally don't want to use document.appendChild when working with React. Instead, you'd define a child component that gets rendered for every element in an array. The array can be held and modified in a state variable. You modify your state, React does the rendering.

Stop using var, use const instead.

Do not interact with the DOM manually when you're using React*. Everything in the code above - including getting the input value, storing the list data, and rendering the list - should be done through the React APIs. I suggest you take a look at the React tutorial as it will help you understand these fundamentals. https://react.dev/learn/tutorial-tic-tac-toe
*There are some exceptions to this rule when you get into some more complex stuff, but you don't need to worry about those at this level.

As others have said: 1) don't try to change the DOM that React controls, this will not work. If you want to manipulate the DOM, don't use React. 2) picture React Function Components (like Todo) as loops: they rerun. React will run var counter = 0 every time this happens (when props or state changes). 3) use Javascript naming conventions. Variable and function names should start with lowercase, React Components and Typescript types names should start with uppercase. 4) use let and const, which avoid some of the gotchas associated with var, and is just the modern way to do things.

When you are using React, you should work with the framework, not against it. With React, you should not have to interact with the real DOM directly.
Instead, use state variables to control the input field's value and to keep track of your todo items in an array. When rendering, transform the array elements into list items with the array index as "counter". React will take care of the rest. You don't have to manipulate the DOM, you don't have to use JavaScript to create elements and append childs. Let React do the heavy lifting.
export default function Todo() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState(''); // start with empty input
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]); // start with empty list of todos

  const addTodo = () => {
    setTodos(todos => [...todos, input]); // never mutate state, always reassign
    setInput(''); // optional: clear input value
  };

  return (
    <>
      <center>
        <h1>Todo</h1>
        <input id="input" type="text"
               value={input} {/* display the value from the state */}
               onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)} {/* update the state */}
               />
        <button onClick={addTodo}>ADD</button>
        <div id="Todo-list">
          {todos.map((todo, idx) => (<li id={`list-val-${idx}`} key={idx}>{todo}</li>))} {/* render one <li> element per todo item in the list */}
        </div>
      </center>
    </>
  )
}

